# css, height of nested flexbox not correct in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have tried to create a basic layout using nested flex boxes. The layout looks fine in IE 11, but the height of the nested flex box is not being set in Chrome.

I have an example here http://jsfiddle.net/jkristia/bL4pyg4b/3/

What am I missing to get this working on Chrome ?

```
<div>
    <!-- header outside flex box -->
    <header class="titlebar">
        <div class="left">This is the left box</div>
        <div class="center">This text is centered in the middle box</div>
        <div class="right">Right box</div>
    </header>
    <!-- flex box -->
    <section class="flexContainer">
        <!-- row using inner flex box -->
        <div class="flexRow">
            <div class="flexContainer02">
                <div class="left">left</div>
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="flexContainer03">
                        <div class="top">center of this div.
                            <br />top</div>
                        <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">right</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">row 3, this is the footer</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

and the css

```
html, body {
    background-color: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.titlebar {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ec7fed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.titlebar .left {
    border: dashed;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #78c6f3;
    /* 
        below is to vertically center the text.
        Set the line height to height of parent element - any padding
    */
    line-height: calc(40px - (5px + 5px));
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.titlebar .center {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    /* flexgrow allows for the box to take the remaining space in the flax container*/
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.titlebar .right {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px;
}
.flexContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 40px);    
    background-color: #d58d28;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}
.flexRow {
    margin:5px;
    flex: 1 100%;
    border: dashed;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
.flexContainer02 {
    margin: 5px;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height:calc(100% - 10px);
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
/* apply the following to all immediate children of flexContainer02*/
 .flexContainer02 > * {
    margin: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    border: dashed;
    border-color: white;
    border-width:1px;
}
.flexContainer02 .left {
    flex: 0 200px;
    background-color: #78c6f3;
}
.flexContainer02 .center {
    flex: 1 200px;
    background-color: #78c6f3;
}
.flexContainer02 .right {
    flex: 0 100px;
    background-color: #9fe1fa
}
/* apply the following to all immediate children of flexContainer03*/
 .flexContainer03 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #86dcc2;
}
.flexContainer03 > * {
    margin: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: darkgrey;
    border-width:1px;
}
.flexContainer03 .top {
    flex: 0 50px;
    background-color: #00ff90;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.flexContainer03 .bottom {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #cbcc80;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #cbce83;
    border: solid;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:right;
    border-color: darkgray;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* for static height set both grow and shrink */
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a colleague found the solution in this codepen
http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/HqgAz

The problem was that I had an extra 'div' for each sub container. The solution is to mark the flex item as a new container by setting display: flex.

I have fixed my jsfiddler example 
http://jsfiddle.net/jkristia/bL4pyg4b/4/

```css
html, body {
 background-color: wheat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.titlebar {
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #ec7fed;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

 .titlebar .left {
  border: dashed;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #78c6f3;
  /* 
  below is to vertically center the text.
  Set the line height to height of parent element - any padding
 */
  line-height: calc(40px - (5px + 5px));
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }

 .titlebar .center {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  /* flexgrow allows for the box to take the remaining space in the flax container*/
  flex-grow: 1;
 }

 .titlebar .right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
 }

.flexContainer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: calc(100% - 40px);
 background-color: #d58d28;
 flex-direction: column;
 display: flex;
}

.flexRow {
 flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin: 5px;
 flex-direction: row;
 background-color: lightgray;
 width: calc(100% - 10px);
 height: calc(100% - 10px);

 margin:5px;
 border: dashed;
 border-color: white;
 border-width: 1px;
}

/* apply the following to all immediate children of .flexRow*/
.flexRow > * {
 margin: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
 border-color: white;
 border-width:1px;
}
.left {
 flex: 0 200px;
 background-color: #78c6f3;
}
.center {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
   width: 100%;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #86dcc2;
}
.right {
 flex: 0 100px;
 background-color: #9fe1fa
}

.center > * {
 margin: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 border: solid;
 border-color: darkgrey;
 border-width: 1px;
}
.center-top {
 flex: 0 40px;
 flex-grow: 0;
 flex-shrink: 0;
 background-color: #00ff90;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.center-bottom {
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 background-color: #cbcc80;
    overflow: auto;
 display: flex;
}

.footer {
 background-color: #cbce83;
 border: solid;
 font-size:12px;
 text-align:right;
 border-color: darkgray;
 border-width: 1px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 /* for static height set both grow and shrink */
 flex-grow: 0;
 flex-shrink: 0;
 height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- header outside flex box -->
  <header class="titlebar">
    <div class="left">
      This is the left box
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      This text is centered in the middle box
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right box
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- flex box -->
  <section class="flexContainer">

    <!-- row using inner flex box -->
    <div class="flexRow">
      <div class="left">
        left
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <div class="center-top">
          center of this div.
          <br />top
        </div>
        <div class="center-bottom">
          bottom
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        right
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      row 3, this is the footer
    </div>

  </section>


</div>
```